How to manage speech_to_text with a Form
In my Flutter application I have a form that saves data to Firestore.
The user must be able to enter data by writing or speaking.
To do this, I have attached the speech_to_text plugin to the form.
The problem is that I haven't found a way to manage speaking and writing together: for example, if the user speaks, then modifies the text, then continues speaking, how can I keep the text properly updated in the TextFormField?
For example, I cannot manage these sequences:

microphone-on, speak, edit, speak
mic-on, speak, mic-off, edit, mic-on, speak

Here is my code:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';

class Speech extends StatefulWidget {
  const Speech({super.key});

  @override
  State<Speech> createState() => _SpeechState();
}

class _SpeechState extends State<Speech> {
  bool _hasSpeech = false;
  String lastWords = '';
  String lastStatus = '';
  final SpeechToText speech = SpeechToText();

  bool textChanged = false;
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeechState();
  }

  Future<void> _initSpeechState() async {
    try {
      bool hasSpeech = await speech.initialize();

      if (!mounted) return;

      setState(() {
        _hasSpeech = hasSpeech;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _hasSpeech = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      // ApplicationState is the widget with the state of my app
      Consumer<ApplicationState>(builder: (context, appState, _) {
        return FutureBuilder<Baby>(
            future: appState.getBabyData(), // I recover the data from Firestore
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Baby> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return MyForm(
                  baby: snapshot.requireData,
                  lastWords: lastWords,
                  descriptionController: _descriptionController,
                  stopListening: stopListening,
                  textChanged: textChanged,
                  setTextChanged: setTextChanged,
                );
              }
            });
      }),
      MicrophoneWidget(speech.isNotListening, startListening, stopListening),
    ]);
  }

  void setTextChanged(changed) {
    setState(() {
      textChanged = changed;
    });
  }

  void startListening() {
    lastWords = '';
    speech.listen(
      onResult: resultListener,
    );
    setState(() {
      textChanged = false;
    });
  }

  void stopListening() {
    speech.stop();
    setState(() {
      textChanged = false;
    });
  }

  void resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      lastWords = result.recognizedWords;
      _descriptionController.text = lastWords;
    });
  }
}

class MicrophoneWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MicrophoneWidget(this.isNotListening, this.startListening, this.stopListening, {super.key});

  final bool isNotListening;
  final void Function() startListening;
  final void Function() stopListening;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: isNotListening ? startListening : stopListening,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
        ),
        child: Icon(isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyForm({
    super.key,
    required this.baby,
    required this.lastWords,
    required this.textChanged,
    required this.setTextChanged,
    required this.descriptionController,
    required this.stopListening,
  });

  final Baby baby;
  final String lastWords;
  final bool textChanged;
  final TextEditingController descriptionController;
  final void Function() stopListening;
  final void Function(bool) setTextChanged;

  @override
  State<MyForm> createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: 'MyFormState');

  void _saveBabyProfile(appState) async {
    widget.stopListening();

    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      widget.baby.description = widget.descriptionController.text;

      // I save the data in Firestore
      appState.setBabyData(widget.baby);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!widget.textChanged) {
      widget.descriptionController.text = widget.lastWords;
      if (widget.baby.description != null) {
        widget.descriptionController.text = '${widget.baby.description} ${widget.lastWords}';
      }
    }

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: widget.descriptionController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              widget.setTextChanged(true);
            },
          ),
          Consumer<ApplicationState>(
            builder: (context, appState, _) => ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _saveBabyProfile(appState),
              child: const Text("Save"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks for your help in advance!

Finally I found how to integrate speech_to_text with a Form.
Here is the updated code:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';

class Speech extends StatefulWidget {
  const Speech({super.key});

  @override
  State<Speech> createState() => _SpeechState();
}

class _SpeechState extends State<Speech> {
  bool _hasSpeech = false;
  String lastWords = '';
  final SpeechToText speech = SpeechToText();

  // I managed `speech_to_text` with the Form through this new variable:
  String lastTextChange = '';

  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeechState();
  }

  Future<void> _initSpeechState() async {
    try {
      bool hasSpeech = await speech.initialize();

      if (!mounted) return;

      setState(() {
        _hasSpeech = hasSpeech;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _hasSpeech = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      // ApplicationState is the widget with the state of my app
      Consumer<ApplicationState>(builder: (context, appState, _) {
        return FutureBuilder<Baby>(
            future: appState.getBabyData(), // I recover the data from Firestore
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Baby> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return MyForm(
                  baby: snapshot.requireData,
                  lastWords: lastWords,
                  descriptionController: _descriptionController,
                  stopListening: stopListening,
                  setLastTextChange: setLastTextChange,
                );
              }
            });
      }),
      MicrophoneWidget(speech.isNotListening, startListening, stopListening),
    ]);
  }

  void setLastTextChange(lastText) {
    lastTextChange = lastText;
  }

  void startListening() {
    lastWords = '';
    speech.listen(
      onResult: resultListener,
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

  void stopListening() {
    speech.stop();
    setState(() {
      lastTextChange = _descriptionController.text;
    });
  }

  void resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    if (result.finalResult) {
      setState(() {
        lastTextChange = _descriptionController.text;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        lastWords = result.recognizedWords;
        _descriptionController.text = '$lastTextChange $lastWords';
      });
    }
  }
}

class MicrophoneWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MicrophoneWidget(this.isNotListening, this.startListening, this.stopListening, {super.key});

  final bool isNotListening;
  final void Function() startListening;
  final void Function() stopListening;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: isNotListening ? startListening : stopListening,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
        ),
        child: Icon(isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyForm({
    super.key,
    required this.baby,
    required this.lastWords,
    required this.descriptionController,
    required this.stopListening,
    required this.setLastTextChange,
  });

  final Baby baby;
  final String lastWords;
  final TextEditingController descriptionController;
  final void Function() stopListening;
  final void Function(String) setLastTextChange;

  @override
  State<MyForm> createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: 'BabyDescriptionFormState');

  void _saveBabyProfile(appState) async {
    widget.stopListening();

    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      widget.baby.description = widget.descriptionController.text;

      // I save the data in Firebase
      appState.setBabyData(widget.baby);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.descriptionController.text = widget.baby.description ?? '';
    widget.setLastTextChange(widget.descriptionController.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: widget.descriptionController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              widget.stopListening();
              widget.setLastTextChange(value);
            },
          ),
          Consumer<ApplicationState>(
            builder: (context, appState, _) => Align(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _saveBabyProfile(appState),
                child: const Text("Save"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Here is the re-produced code. I Tried these sequences 1) microphone-on, speak, edit, speak 2) mic-on, speak, mic-off, edit, mic-on, speak. And it's working fine. Replace the Baby and ApplicationState with your original code.

Thanks, but onChanged is called with every change made to TextFormField, so with every character inserted it would save the data to Firestore. I would like the user to save the data in Firestore only at the end.

If you don't want to upload data every time some text changes, you can follow this. Please check I've updated the answer.

I had already tried this solution, but if the user then starts talking again the changes are overwritten. I can't find the right way to switch between spoken and text edits!

In my case, it's working perfectly. Can you please share the code of your Baby and ApplicationState?

Before sharing the code, just to be sure, have you tried these sequences? 1) microphone-on, speak, edit, speak 2) mic-on, speak, mic-off, edit, mic-on, speak

Check please I've updated the answer.

I don't understand some things in your code: in the resultListener function, the code inside the if else is the same. Are you sure you have shared the latest version of the code? Because the code still doesn't work for me...

Take the whole snippet and run it on your device. Without editing anything. I tried to fill your requirements. After checking then you can replace your database code.

Sorry, your code works, but not as I would like.
I didn't notice right away because now he writes everything when the mic stops, right?
Unfortunately I need the app to transcribe everything that is said word for word, and I haven't found a way to do that yet, but thanks to you I've made some progress!
